# Use of getSampleWidth() and getSampleHeight() in javafx

Tags: javafx

I have seen in many a program these two things usually towards the end of the program and I have no clue how they operate.

What is the purpose of adding them?
getSampleWidth() and getSampleHeight()

http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2/samples/Ensemble/index.html#SAMPLES/Language/Beans/Change Listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**

You can completely ignore the `getSampleWidth()` and `getSampleHeight()` methods.

The methods are not part of the JavaFX api and would never be present in a "normal" JavaFX application.

**Background**

The JavaFX 2 Ensemble application is a suite of small application samples, each of which demonstrate an aspect of JavaFX technology, such as playing media, using a particular control or executing an animation technique.  Each of these individual samples is hosted inside a larger application (Ensemble) which serves as the UI for accessing and executing each of the sample applications.

Ensemble makes each sample application extend a Sample interface (created only for the Ensemble Application) which provides access to sample meta-data, a couple of these metadata access methods are the `getSampleWidth()` and `getSampleHeight()` methods.

A normal JavaFX application is not a sample to run in Ensemble, so it will not implement the Ensemble specific Sample interface.

The Ensemble application and its source code is available from the [Java SE downloads page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) by downloading the "JDK 8 Demos and Samples".  Ensemble has been rewritten for Java 8 and makes a good study when first learning JavaFX APIs (though not for learning about FXML based development).